# Q4Wine can't find wine binaries

Tags: 20.04, wine

After installing Q4Wine, when I launch it, it shows "`Cannot find or execute the 'wine' binary`."

It also can't find the `wineserver` binary

[image: wine-binary]

According to [BrezBlock.org](https://q4wine.brezblock.org.ua/documentation/en_us/03-first-startup-wizard.html), those files should be present in the `/usr/bin` directory, (As in this image)

[image: wine_path]

but I can't find any file named `wine` or `wineserver` over there.

Does anybody knows how to fix this issue...

Comment: How did you installed Q4Wine? Using deb/APT repository or other way?

Comment: From the Software Center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to simply install missed `wine` package by:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```

and then restart Q4Wine application.

---

The problem is a bit unpredicted as `q4wine` deb-package should install wine [by itself](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/q4wine) as dependency (recommendation).

Comment: After running the command it displays, E: Package 'wine' has no installation candidate.

Comment: Check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's the exact problem with Q4wine, but installing another package wine, from the software center fixed the issue.

After installing wine, Q4wine runs perfectly.